# Reversing modulo to get unknown value

Tags: python, algorithm, modulo

I am looking to solve this modulo operator problem for an encryption algorithm similar to RSA (not exactly the same) but I am not used to using the modulo operator.

I have four values as is what I found to be optimal. There is a message, a cypher and two keys (public and private). message = m, cypher = c, public key = n, private key = e. In the end, I will have both keys and the cypher but not the message.

For my original encryption equation, I used:

```
c = (m + e) % n
```

For decryption, I used this:

```
m = (c - e) % n
```

But it didn't prove as simple when I decided to replace add and subtract with multiply and divide:

```
c = (m * e) % n
m != (c / e) % n
```

In the end, I would like to achieve the first result with:

```
c = (m ** e) % n
```

In conclusion, I have `c = 8 (12)(13), e = 41, n = 63` and I know that `m = 34` but I don't know how to calculate it.

```
8 = (m * 41) % 63
(12 = (m + 41) % 63)
(13 = (m ** 41) % 63)
```

Comment: The modulo is reversible for values `<= n` only.

Comment: To me what you are asking about is an algorithm and questions of this sort are much more suited to [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange forum.

Comment: What you are doing is completely unlike how RSA works (even insecure "textbook" RSA). You should go back and read how RSA is supposed to work again.

Comment: Additionally, I would recommend reading Wikipedia page about [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) which is what you seem to be asking about here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm you are looking for is [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) (there is a pseudocode there) for a mathematical problem of [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) and it has a [question on Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/47833/computing-mod-inverse/47853#47853) as well

Comment: Thanks for the help, I understand that my question might be in the wrong place but I don't use Stack that much so I pretty much ask most of my questions here. If I offended anyone then that person should learn to be more patient and not take offence on trivial matters.

Comment: @VLR1275 - just to clarify - it is not about an offence (none taken) but rather about an ongoing attempt by the community to ensure the best possible structure of information for the benefit of information/solution seekers.

Comment: I will take care to ask the right questions in the future